# Does any SQL standard include a REF CURSOR or TABLE type definition?

Tags: sql, standards, ref-cursor, nested-table

I always find it hard to read the rather abstract SQL standard specification, for instance this document here:

http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

I'm wondering, is any of the major RDBMS's supported concepts of REF CURSOR's (Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, ...), or TABLE types (which can be used as nested tables, e.g. in Oracle), or any related concept standardised in some way?

For instance, HSQLDB, a very standards-compliant database (since version 2.0) supports the `UNNEST` function to unnest `ARRAY` types into tables. This concept of unnesting can be considered part of the [non-first normal form in relational modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Non-first_normal_form_.28NF.C2.B2_or_N1NF.29), which seems to be a common concept. That's why I thought it might be worth standardising...

Comment: Oracle supports `REF CURSOR` - but I think that's an Oracle-specific extension, not part of any ANSI standard (could be wrong though). Also: SQL1992 standard is pretty old - SQL:2008 is the most recent, officially defined standard (as far as I know)

Comment: @marc: Thanks, I know about Oracle's `REF CURSOR`, that's why I put it in the question... ;-) I have access to most draft documents for SQL standards. I feel there hadn't been many relevant additions regarding this topic, but as I said, I find it hard to read those documents. So I'm really looking for a pointer